# Can my remote-controlled ceiling fan be connected to a wall switch?

Tags: electrical, fans

My Casablanca fan remote control no longer works and I have to turn the breaker on and off every time. They no longer have a remote control replacement. Can I have an electrician connect it to a switch on the wall?

Answer (score 2):

Probably. The receiver is usually just a box that can be removed, and the wires from the ceiling connected directly to the wires for the fan/light.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an electrician wire it to a switch but that will probably be expensive. You can buy a new remote control and receiver from your home store or amazon. They are inexpensive and easy to install but you'd need to take down the fan so have someone help you if you're going to do it yourself.

Does your fan have a chain pull switch?  It would save you from having to operate the breaker each time to control the fan.